# In django's view.py, I want to change it to a string form rather than a json form

Tags: python, reactjs, django

django:

```
view.py

    class ListPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
        serializer_class = PalyerListSerializer
```

react:

```
console.log(player)

    (4) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
    0: {d_code: 4, name: "test4", position: "RW", code: 1}
    1: {d_code: 3, name: "test3", position: "ST", code: 2}
    2: {d_code: 2, name: "test2", position: "LB", code: 2}
    3: {d_code: 1, name: "test1", position: "RB", code: 1}
    length: 4
    __proto__: Array(0)
```

When I use console.log I want it to be output in string format.

I can't use JSON.stringify as I can use the map function.

I want to convert it to string format in view.py.

How can I convert it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to override your list method and dump your JSON object:

```
import json

    class ListPlayer(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = PlayerList.objects.all().order_by('-d_code')
        serializer_class = PalyerListSerializer

        def list(self, request):
            queryset = self.get_queryset()
            serializer = PalyerListSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(json.dumps(serializer.data))
```